# CORS error on local site

Tags: cdp

I have started learning Sitecore **CDP**. I had the sample site hosted on the local machine and browse the page. I'm trying to connect the app. box ever with a valid app_key and point of sale. I have faced a Cors origin error in the console.

Anyone help me how to resolve this error and how to enable cross in **app.boxever.com**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, your site is not hosted on `https`.

Secondly, you are calling a `https` CDP endpoint from a `http` website which will likely cause the browser to throw this `CORS` error.

I'd suggest to host your site on `https` to get rid of this error.

Comment: faced same error after applying https.